# How do I reset variables to original value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I reset the global variables back to the original values (in this case all 0's) without having to call them as a this. variables in the function.

Example:

Here is a snippet of what im doing (only showing 5 of the 27 variables):

```
priority1 = 0;
priority2 = 0;
priority3 = 0;
priority4 = 0;
priority5 = 0;
```

I then have a function that works out some data eg:

```
processAllDashboardData(assetType) {
    this.dataSource.filteredData.forEach((element, key) => {
      if (element.assetType === assetType) {
        if (element.stage === 'OPEN') {
          element.priority === 'Priority 1' && this.priority1++;
          element.priority === 'Priority 2' && this.priority2++;
          element.priority === 'Priority 3' && this.priority3++;
          element.priority === 'Priority 4' && this.priority4++;
          element.priority === 'Priority 5' && this.priority5++;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The function - processAllDashboardData() - is called the first time the dashboard is open and works out values for all assetTypes. If I change the assetType so its only adding for a specific type, the function gets called again and depending on what value is passed across it will only add up those for that assetType. The problem is, because the page does not reload, the variables still contain the values and so the new amount is added on top of the old one.

I know that I could do:

```
filterByType(assetType) {
this.priority1 = 0;
this.priority2 = 0;
this.priority3 = 0;
this.priority4 = 0;
priority5 = 0;
processAllDashboardData(assetType);
}
```

But i have 27 variables that are being used and so I thought there must be a better way of setting all values back to the original 0 rather than having another 27 lines of 0's when its already set at the top of the page. I know there is the option of a shorthand by just making it:

```
this.priority1 = this.priority2 = this.priority3 = this.priority4 = this.priority 5 = 0;
```

But again, with 27 variables the line becomes very long and hard to read.

Hope the question makes sense, any help appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using an array? 

Comment: Why not do the initialization in a function and just that function whenever you wish to re-initialize.

Comment: @cup thats what I want - a function to initialise them all but not sure how.

Comment: @cup Also not all the variables are priority - I have the following as well: 
  
numOpenCases: 0,
    closedYear: 0,
    closedMonth: 0,
    closedWeek: 0,
    mttrClosedCases: 0,
    met: 0,
    breached: 0,
    metPercentage: 0,
    breachedPercentage: 0,
    withCustomer: 0,
    withAMCS: 0,

    withCustomerPercentage: 0,
    backlog120: 0,
    backlog90: 0,
    backlog119: 0,
    backlog60: 0,
    backlog89: 0,
    backlog30: 0,
    backlog59: 0,
    backlog29: 0,

Answer (score 0):

You could try declaring all the variables as one object:

```
priorities = {
   priority1: 0,
   priority2: 0,
   priority3: 0,
   priority4: 0
}
```

to reset them all you would simply need to loop through the object, using for example Object.entries()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

or:

```
for (let key in priorities) {
  priorities[key] = 0;
}
```

Comment: I have more than just priority so I wasn't sure how the array would work. Especially since when looping through the element name is not always the same as the variable name. For instance there is a case where it is a time, and the variable is just a count on how many times those cases appear within the timezone.

There is a variable backlog120 = 0; and 
backlogDate120 = moment().subtract(120, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

Then in the code I would have: 

element.createddate <= this.backlogDate120 && this.backlog120++;